# Local Storage on GhettoVCB

Tags: vmware-esxi

Trying to run GhettoVCB as a test on ESXI 5.0 Host. Here is my configuration

```
VM_BACKUP_VOLUME=/Datastore1/BACKUPS
DISK_BACKUP_FORMAT=thin
VM_BACKUP_ROTATION_COUNT=3
POWER_VM_DOWN_BEFORE_BACKUP=0
ENABLE_HARD_POWER_OFF=0
ITER_TO_WAIT_SHUTDOWN=3
POWER_DOWN_TIMEOUT=5
ENABLE_COMPRESSION=0
VM_SNAPSHOT_MEMORY=0
VM_SNAPSHOT_QUIESCE=0
ENABLE_NON_PERSISTENT_NFS=0
UNMOUNT_NFS=0
NFS_SERVER=
NFS_MOUNT=
NFS_LOCAL_NAME=
NFS_VM_BACKUP_DIR=
SNAPSHOT_TIMEOUT=15
EMAIL_LOG=0
EMAIL_DEBUG=0
EMAIL_SERVER=auroa.primp-industries.com
EMAIL_SERVER_PORT=25
EMAIL_DELAY_INTERVAL=1
EMAIL_TO=auroa@primp-industries.com
```

I am trying to run this thing locally but everytime I do it says datastore not found. I am positive I am doing something wrong here, any ideas? Here is the debug output.

```
 ============================== ghettoVCB LOG START ==============================

2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- debug: Succesfully acquired lock directory - /tmp/ghettoVCB.lock

2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- debug: HOST VERSION: VMware ESXi 5.0.0 build-623860
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- debug: HOST LEVEL: VMware ESXi 5.0.0 Update 1
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- debug: HOSTNAME: vm5.smarterdedicatedserver.com

2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VERSION = 2011_11_19_1
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - GHETTOVCB_PID = 1087454
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VM_BACKUP_VOLUME = /vmfs/volumes/dlgCore-NFS-bigboi.VM-Backups/WILLIAM_BACKUPS
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VM_BACKUP_ROTATION_COUNT = 3
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VM_BACKUP_DIR_NAMING_CONVENTION = 2012-10-11_02-25-52
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - DISK_BACKUP_FORMAT = thin
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - POWER_VM_DOWN_BEFORE_BACKUP = 0
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - ENABLE_HARD_POWER_OFF = 0
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - ITER_TO_WAIT_SHUTDOWN = 3
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - POWER_DOWN_TIMEOUT = 5
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - SNAPSHOT_TIMEOUT = 15
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - LOG_LEVEL = debug
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - BACKUP_LOG_OUTPUT = /tmp/ghettoVCB-2012-10-11_02-25-52.log
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VM_SNAPSHOT_MEMORY = 0
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VM_SNAPSHOT_QUIESCE = 0
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - VMDK_FILES_TO_BACKUP = all
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info: CONFIG - EMAIL_LOG = 0
2012-10-11 02:25:52 -- info:
Datastore not found.

Datastore not found.

Datastore not found.

2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: Storage Information before backup:
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: SRC_DATASTORE: datastore1
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: SRC_DATASTORE_CAPACITY: 1858.0 GB
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: SRC_DATASTORE_FREE: 1415.5 GB
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: SRC_DATASTORE_BLOCKSIZE: 1
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: SRC_DATASTORE_MAX_FILE_SIZE: 256 GB
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug:
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: DST_DATASTORE: dlgCore-NFS-bigboi.VM-Backups
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: DST_DATASTORE_CAPACITY: 0.0 GB
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: DST_DATASTORE_FREE: 0.0 GB
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: DST_DATASTORE_BLOCKSIZE: NA
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: DST_DATASTORE_MAX_FILE_SIZE: NA
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug:
2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- info: Snapshot found for VM1-680, backup will not take place

2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- info: ###### Final status: ERROR: All VMs failed! ######

2012-10-11 02:25:54 -- debug: Succesfully removed lock directory - /tmp/ghettoVCB.lock
```

Also no clue where it is getting dlgCore-NFS-bigboi.VM-Backups as a DST_DATASTORE, must be a default, any help would be awsome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dlgCore-NFS-bigboi.VM-Backups is a default in ghettoVCB.sh itself. Try specifying your config file in the ghettoVCB command with `-g ghettoVCB.conf` or whatever the path to your config file is.

Comment: Thanks for the response, not the right answer but it got me to the right answer. Basically there is stuff that needs to be modified not just in the .conf file but in the sh file itself towards the very top. I got to wondering where it was getting that path from and sure enough at the top of the sh file it was there.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem you need to go directly in the ghettoVCB file itself and modify the target datastore. Initially i thought all configuration was done in the .conf file but this is not the case apparently.

Answer (score 0):

@Al Katawazi. hwilbanks gave the right answer. You don't need to modify the sh file, rather you need to provide your conf file as an argument while issuing the backup command e.g.

```
./ghettoVCB.sh -f backup_vm -g ghettoVCB.conf
```

Where `backup_vm` is the file which includes the list of vms to be backed up and `gettoVCB.conf` is the file which includes all the configurations.